# Add asp.net update panel linkbutton not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

In my webapplication page ,top of the page contain seven linkbutton .So i am adding asp.net update panel .After including that the linkbutton events are not worked.Without using the update panel it work well. How can I solve the problem?
Here is my code:

```
 <div class="container">
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
    <div class="col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0s">
        <div class="filter_menu ">
            <div class="boltsort">Sort By:</div>
            <div class="boltsortlist">                
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkrecomm" runat="server">Recommended</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkrating" runat="server">User Rating</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp; 
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkprice" runat="server" OnClick="lkprice_Click">Price</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkDistance" runat="server" OnClick="lkDistance_Click">Distance</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkA_Z" runat="server" OnClick="lkA_Z_Click" Text="A-Z"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkNewest" runat="server" OnClick="lkNewest_Click">Newest</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkHalal" runat="server" OnClick="lkHalal_Click">Halal</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="left_side_choose_list">
    <div class="select_rest">
    <p class="left_span">Choose Multi / Restaurant</p>
    <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
    <div class="top_arrow dl-trigger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></div>
    <div class="menu_list dl-menu">
    <div class="all_menu text-left">Available Restaurant near you..</div>
    <div class="panel-group null_margin" id="accordion">
    <asp:ListView ID="LvCuisine" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound">             
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="accoring panel-default">
    <div class="accor_styles text-left">
    <a class="accordion-toggle panel-title" data-toggle="collapse-next" data-parent=".accoring"> 
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdCuisineID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CuisineName")%>'  CssClass="ui-checkboxcuisine" ID="chk11"  />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body padd_null text-left">
    <div class="driving-license-kind">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RptItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="checkbox_accor">
    <div id="chkdiv">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdRID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RID") %>' />
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RestaurantTitle")%>' CssClass="ui-checkbox "  />
    </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>     
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate></asp:ListView>
    <asp:Button ID="btndone" runat="server" class="btn accor_btn pull-right test"  Text="Done" OnClick="btndone_Click" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
            <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-wow-delay="0s">
            <asp:ListView ID="lvRestaurants" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lvRestaurants_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="a_brandstore_details12 ">
            <div class="a_pro_inner">
            <div class="a_brand_logo">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image2" Width="133px" Height="113px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath")%>' /></div>
            <div class="a_details fix_width">
            <div class="a_name">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Resttitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RestaurantTitle")%>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="a_address123">
            <div class="a_brad_food">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Cuisines" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CuisineName")%>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="a_order_rating">
            <img src="/CustomerPortalTemplate/images/rating.jpg"></div>               
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="brand_details">
            <div class="a_address123">
            <div class="a_brad_open">
            Open at :
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("OpenTime") %>' runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="a_deli_time">Delivery Fee : $ 1.0</div>
            <div class="a_order">Minimum Order :
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("MinimumOrder") %>' runat="server" /></div>
             <div class="avilable_range">
            <div class="icons_place"><asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# (bool)Eval("WirelessFacility")==true ? "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/wi-fi.png" : "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/wi-fi_r.png" %>' runat="server"/></div>
            <div class="icons_place"><asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# (bool)Eval("ParkingFacility")==true ? "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/parking.png" : "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/parking_r.png" %>' runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="icons_place"><asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# (bool)Eval("DisableAccess")==true ? "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/disabled.png" : "/CustomerPortalTemplate/img/disabled_r.png" %>' runat="server" /></div>
            </div>


            <asp:Label ID="lbldist" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Distance")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom_buttons">
            <div class="button_div text-left fix_width ">
            <input type="button" value="Group Order" class="btn restaurant_btn ">
            </div>
            <div class="button_div text-left padd_left_50">
            <input type="button" value="Book Table" class="btn restaurant_btn ">
            </div>
            <div class="button_div text-left">
            <asp:Button ID="btnorder" class="btn restaurant_btn" Text='<%# Eval("BUTTONNAME")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")+ ","+Eval("RestaurantTitle") %>' CommandName="OrderRestId" runat="server"></asp:Button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="a_brand_offer123 hidden-390" style="background: url(/CustomerPortalTemplate/images/offer-bg.png) no-repeat">
            <span class="offer">20%</span><br />
            <span class="offer">OFF</span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `UpdateMode` to `Always` on the updatepanel ?

Comment: Setting UpdateMode to Always .but i didn't get the output